# Swipe on ListView inside FrameLayout not working

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, swipe, ontouchlistener

In my android-app I have a Layout consisting of a `FrameLayout` containing a `GridView`.
Each grid cell consists of one `RelativeLayout` with a `TextView` and a `ListView` within.

Now I tried to swipe right and left. For this, I implemented an `OnSwipeTouchListener` based on the SO-Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures) and added it to the `FrameLayout`.

Now, everything works fine. Except if I want to swipe over a `ListView`. If I swipe on a `ListView` the app doesn't do anything. I think it's because the `ListView` captures somehow the TouchEvents itself, without letting my Activity know that there was a TouchEvent at all.

My layout is the following:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.Test"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="16"
        android:rowCount="8"
        android:id="@+id/grid">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/ll3"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Montag"
                android:textSize="40px"
                android:background="#66ff66"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_height="55px"
                android:id="@+id/tv1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" />

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv1"
                android:id="@+id/l1">
            </ListView>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </GridLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I set the OnSwipeTouchListener like this:

```
frameLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this));
```

I think I'm missing something on the `ListView`-Side, something like disabling touch on a ListView at all.

Has anyone had this problem too or knows a Solution for this?

Comment: you can set  ontouchlistener on list view and handle them according your need.

Comment: I don't need to swipe on the ListView. I need to swipe on the whole layout. Or do you mean, I should - additionally - set the same TouchListener to all of my ListViews too?

Comment: yeah.. exactly.. handle touchevents on list view as per your need.

Comment: Hmm okay. For me, this could work because I have 'only' 8 ListViews. But what would I do if I had, let's say, 30 ListViews? Don't get me wrong, but this would IMO be against the principles of DRY...

Comment: Where DRY principles getting violated. you can use custom listview at all places.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use swipes combined with ListView scrolling.
That's because parent (FrameLayout) method [onInterceptTouchEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) returns false, and your FrameLayout don't want to receive any events more, because ListView is scroll container.

You can extend FrameLayout & do something special in onInterceptTouchEvent method for achieve your goals